# Which static spherically symmetric perfect fluid solutions of Einstein field equations are known to be suitable for stellar models?

Tags: star, general-relativity, modeling

Wikipedia's ([Static spherically symmetric perfect fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spherically_symmetric_perfect_fluid)) short list ends in 2005 and lists only in total 5 such solutions. Does somebody know more?

Comment: Note that the paragraph in the wiki article just seems to be a copypaste from some research article, without proper referencing.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape You are probably right. Wiki is not a reliable source for scientific information. I will have to look into astronomical journals.